# Change the color widget by using GPIO in Raspberry

Tags: python-2.7, colors, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkFont
    import Tkinter
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN)


    class PersamaanKuadrat:
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            self.parent = parent

            #self.parent.geometry("1280x560")
            self.parent.title(title)
            self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")

            self.aturKomponen()



        def aturKomponen(self):

            self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=18)

            mainCanvas = Canvas(self.parent, width=1300, height=600, bg="grey")
            mainCanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

            self.kanvas = mainCanvas


            self.btnCariAkar = Button(mainCanvas, text="ENTER!",
                command=exit)
            self.btnCariAkar.place(relx=.25, rely=.25)

            self.btn1= Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="A1", bg="white")
            self.btn1.place(relx=.65, rely=.25)

            self.btn2 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="A2", bg="white")
            self.btn2.place(relx=.80, rely=.25)

            self.btn3 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="B1", bg="white")
            self.btn3.place(relx=.65, rely=.55)


            self.btn4 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="B2", bg="white")
            self.btn4.place(relx=.80, rely=.55)

        def atur(self):
            inputValue = GPIO.input(10)
            if(inputValue == True):
                self.btn1.configure(bg="yellow")
            else:
                self.btn1.configure(bg="red")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()

        aplikasi = PersamaanKuadrat(root, "T")

        root.mainloop()
```

1. I want change the color of btn1 by pressing push-button which connected to GPIO pin (pin 10), for example, if I push the button, the btn1 will have yellow color, if i dont push it the color will be red. when I run the module there is no error, and the program works. but when I pushed the push button, the btn1's color didn't change. I Can't find the mistake, can you all help me.
2. If I want to add timer function, for example after 30 seconds, the color of btn1 will change from yellow back to red, is it possible?
3. can I use 'and' for this program. for example if I want to use 2 buttons to change it to green, what should I do?

Need Help, because I'm a newbie for this raspberry thing, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think you need timer to run `atur()` to test if push-button was pressed. Now program doesn't know that you pressed push-button

In `__init__()` and in `atur()`:

```
self.parent.after(10, self.atur)
```

2) Yes it is possible with `self.parent.after(milliseconds, function_name)`

3) Do you mean two push-button connected to GPIO ? I think yes.

---

**EDIT:**

Example with timer changing `btn2` color every 500ms.
I think now program should change `btn1` color by pressing push-button. (not tested)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import Tkinter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN)


class PersamaanKuadrat:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent

        #self.parent.geometry("1280x560")
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")

        self.aturKomponen()

        self.parent.after(10, self.atur)
        self.parent.after(500, self.change_color)


    def aturKomponen(self):

        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=18)

        mainCanvas = Canvas(self.parent, width=1300, height=600, bg="grey")
        mainCanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.kanvas = mainCanvas


        self.btnCariAkar = Button(mainCanvas, text="ENTER!",
            command=exit)
        self.btnCariAkar.place(relx=.25, rely=.25)

        self.btn1= Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="A1", bg="white")
        self.btn1.place(relx=.65, rely=.25)

        self.btn2 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="A2", bg="white")
        self.btn2.place(relx=.80, rely=.25)

        self.btn3 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="B1", bg="white")
        self.btn3.place(relx=.65, rely=.55)


        self.btn4 = Button(mainCanvas, padx=30, pady=30, text="B2", bg="white")
        self.btn4.place(relx=.80, rely=.55)

    def atur(self):
        print "test push-button"
        inputValue = GPIO.input(10)
        if(inputValue == True):
            self.btn1.configure(bg="yellow")
        else:
            self.btn1.configure(bg="red")
        self.parent.after(10, self.atur)

    def change_color(self):
        print "change_color"
        if self.btn2['bg'] == 'yellow':
            self.btn2['bg'] = 'red'
        else: 
            self.btn2['bg'] = 'yellow'
        self.parent.after(500, self.change_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    aplikasi = PersamaanKuadrat(root, "T")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks furas, it Helps me a lot, can I contact you, actually I found a new problem, and I wanna ask you directly, If you don't mind of course :)

Comment: my email: furas@tlen.pl